# Does -DNDEBUG intefere with -g flag?

Tags: c

I had two questions regarding the -DNDEBUG that I didnt quite understand after doing some reading on it.

1) Will it cause problems if both -DNDEBUG and -g flags are used together?

2) Does the -DNDEBUG flag turn off asserts? (This means that asserts wont work)

Comment: 1. Not it won't. 2. Yes it does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To expand [@kaylum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3003365/kaylum)'s valid answer.

`-DNDEBUG` consists of two parts, the flag `-D` and the argument `NDEBUG`. The flag is used to create preprocessor defines, therefore this will create a new preprocessor `#define` called `NDEBUG`

`-g` is a compiler switch to generate debugging information. It works completely separate from creating defines with `-D`. Read more about debugging flags [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html).